# How can I run a function against the same column in multiple data frames?

Tags: r

I have eight data frames and wish to run `table(dfX$TestDay)` against all of them.

I could write them out manually:

```
table(df1$TestDay)
table(df2$TestDay)
...
table(df8$TestDay)
```

But the number of data frames is likely to increase and, over time, this will not be a feasible approach.

I suspect that an `apply` function would be the solution here, but I am unsure how to implement one.

How can this be done?

Sample data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = runif(21, 1, 21), TestDay = rep(c("m","t","w","th","f","sa","su"), 3))

df2 <- data.frame(id = runif(21, 1, 21), TestDay = rep(c("m","t","w","th","f","sa","su"), 3))

df3 <- data.frame(id = runif(21, 1, 21), TestDay = rep(c("m","t","w","th","f","sa","su"), 3))

df4 <- data.frame(id = runif(21, 1, 21), TestDay = rep(c("m","t","w","th","f","sa","su"), 3))
```

Comment: `lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'df[0-9]+')), function(i)table(i$TestDay))`

Comment: **Do not** create multiple variables with the same name like this. Use lists instead, that’s what they’re for. Not using lists here is a basic beginner’s mistake. Once you have all your data.frames inside a list, the problem is trivial to solve (e.g. as `lapply(df_list, \(x) table(x$TestDay))`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have actually already placed them in a list in anticipation of such an approach.

Comment: @Mus OK, then that’s the solution.

Comment: @KonradRudolph What does the `\(x)` do in your example?

Comment: @Mus It’s a shortcut for `function (x)` since R 4.1.